# Check if last taken Map element is last

Tags: java, hashmap

Faced a problem where I need to put elements in two different Maps and after go through all of them and put if condition on the last element of the last Map.

Here I have code I've tried:

```
private Map<Integer, String> testing1 = new TreeMap<>();
private Map<Integer, String> testing2 = new TreeMap<>();

testing1.put(1, "one");
testing1.put(2, "two");
testing2.put(3, "three");
testing2.put(4, "four");
```

Now I have two for loops where I want to check if both for loops have last element right now:
I have tried with .size() but that didn't help with Map

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> something: testing1.entrySet()) {
  for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> something2: testing2.entrySet()) {
     if(){
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: *I want to check if both for loops have last element right now* which last element?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean " _I have two maps here: map *A* and *B*. I want to know which map ( *A* or *B*) has the last element._ " ? Also how do you consider when an element is "last"? By the Integer key?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know when will happen the end of the loops? Following your example, do you want to know when the `for testing1` has `<2, "two">` and `for testing2` has `<4, "four">`?

Comment: @Shirkam,  nagendra547 solution is exactly, what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, this will be really useful for you.

**lastKey** method of TreeMap.

```
Map<Integer, String> testing1 = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> testing2 = new TreeMap<>();

testing1.put(1, "one");
testing1.put(2, "two");
testing2.put(3, "three");
testing2.put(4, "four");

int lastKey1 = ((TreeMap<Integer, String>) testing1).lastKey();
int lastKey2 = ((TreeMap<Integer, String>) testing2).lastKey();
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> something: testing1.entrySet()) {
      for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> something2: testing2.entrySet()) {
         if(something.getKey() == lastKey1  && something2.getKey() == lastKey2){
             // do your work
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are those two loops not obsolete? You already have the two last keys? ( disclaimer: _Tbf, I don't understand the reason of the two loops in the OP's question because the question is vague itself_ )

Comment: Yes, you are right in some aspects. If OP is looking to get last keys from map, he/she can directly use it.  However, if OP is doing some specific operations based in the two loops then he/she can use the comparison logic.

Comment: That is an incredible solution. Thank you, it helped so much.

Comment: I had to use both of lastKey finders cause I have two dropdown boxes and I want to be 100% sure that both of them are last. Else I do other stuff.
@KarelG